# Failover Clustering with live client connections

Tags: high-availability

I need to deploy an FTP server in a high-availability configuration.

So far I've used Windows Failover clustering (using Win 2k8 Enterprise) and DRBD in Linux. Both do enable me to develop a failover cluster for the FTP service. But when a failure occurs all client connections that are using the server are lost. Clients have to reconnect and restart/resume their upload/downloads.

Is there a technology that can be used to provide failover support while maintaining client connections?

Answer (score 0):

When server fails, the connection is closed and even by using application level proxy it is not possible to continue because during upload to the crashed server it is not possible to resume and the file would have to be re-uploaded.
Still, maybe you can make your ftp clients behave intelligently the way that they would automatically resume downloading or uploading from start.